# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-chrome, wpml

I'm having a weird issue, wordpress homepage has a 302 error (redirection loop) on Google Chrome only, however if I access my admin panel first and then go back to homepage, it works...
I have WPML installed and Yoast SEO.
Installation is in a subfolder.

Would somebody have an idea of what is going on?

Here is the link: [www.scrybs.com](http://www.scrybs.com)

Thanks in advance

My htaccess is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/$ /auth/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/login$ /auth/login.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/logout$ /auth/logout.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/registration$ /auth/registration_form.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/password-forgotten$ /auth/forgot_form.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/facebook$ /auth/facebook_connect.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/reset$ /auth/reset.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/activate$ /auth/activate.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/$ /account/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/$ /account/t/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/jobs/$ /account/t/jobs.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/myjobs/$ /account/t/myjobs.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/myaccount/$ /account/t/myaccount.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/([^/]*)$ /account/t/?lang=$1&step=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/tests/$ /account/t/testspage.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/jobs/([^/]*)/$ /account/t/orderpage.php?lang=$1&ref=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/transactions/$ /account/t/transactions.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/$ /account/c/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/([^/]*)$ /account/c/?lang=$1&step=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/myorders/$ /account/c/myorders.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/myaccount/$ /account/c/myaccount.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/myorders/([^/]*)/$ /account/c/orderpage.php?lang=$1&ref=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/transactions/$ /account/c/transactions.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/order/$ /order/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/order/reference/([^/]*)/$ /order/reference.php?lang=$1&ref=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/support/$ /support/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/support/requests/new/$ /support/requests/newrequest.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/support/translators/$ /support/translators.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/support/topics/([^-]+)-([^/]+)$ /support/topic.php?lang=$1&id=$2&url=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/guest-tracking/$ /guest-tracking/?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added my htaccess content however if it was htaccess I wouldn't be able to access homepage after going to admin panel. I'm willing to pay to solve this issue!!!

Comment: @ JordanBelfort17 .Can you tell me whats problem?

Comment: @VasimVanzara I was down voted for no reason. Basically the issue is that we can't access the homepage. If we go to another page and then come back to homepage, it's working...If we go to another page and clear cache and cookies, we can't access the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in the configuration of your server versus WP domain configuration, that make an infinity loop. Check if the domain is the same in both places